# `set_sorted` when a dataframe is sorted on multiple columns

Tags: python-polars

I have some panel data in polars. The dataframe is sorted by its id column and then its date column (basically it's a bunch of time series concatenated together).

I've seen that polars has a `.set_sorted` method for working with expressions. I can of course set `pl.col("id").set_sorted()` but I want it to be aware that it's actually sorted in both id and date columns. In pandas I know the Index has an `.is_monotonic_increasing` property that is aware of whether all the columns of the Index are sorted but is there a way to do something similar with polars?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
df.get_column('id').is_sorted()
```

and

```
df.get_column('date').is_sorted()
```

to see if they're each already known to be sorted?

For instance if I do:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4]})
df.get_column('a').is_sorted()
df.get_column('b').is_sorted()
```

Then I get 2 Trues even though I haven't ever told it that the columns are sorted.

In general, I don't think you want to be manually setting columns as sorted.  Just sort them and it'll keep track of the fact that they're sorted.

If you do:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,2], 'b':[1,3,2,4]})
df.get_column('a').is_sorted()
df.get_column('b').is_sorted()
```

then you get False twice, as you'd hope.  If you then do `df=df.sort(['a','b'])` and follow it up by checking the sortedness of a and b again then you see that it knows they're sorted

Comment: My data looks more like the following `df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2], 'b':[1,2,3,1,2]})`. There are other "data" columns but `a` and `b` basically form the index. Here polars knows that it is sorted by `a`. But I want it to know that is jointly sorted by `a` and then `b`.

Ideally I wouldn't need to designated the sortedness myself but often the data comes from a parquet file from another program. I know apriori that it's sorted but I want to make sure polars knows about it